# {{}} i found this in html script tag

Tags: javascript, html

> ```
> what is {{}} in script tag in index.html page 
> `<script type="text/tmpl" id="tmpl">
>         {{ 
>
>         if (mode === 'day') {
>           thedate = new Date(date);
>           first = new Date(thedate);
>           last = new Date(thedate);
>           last.setDate(thedate.getDate() + 1);
>         }
>
>         }}
> </script>`
> ```

What is the use of double curly braces in html script tag

Comment: It's a template script, the double curly braces mark some code to run/replaced by a template engine, either on the server, or with JS on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These curly braces are most likely a remnant from code templating. Code templating is where an engine (either on the server or the client) replaces a section of code. You can see some more examples of templating in the Wikipedia article for [JavaScript templating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_templating).

The other (less likely) reason is that it's a mistake.